# Jetpack Compose androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope - receiver type mismatch

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

UPDATE: As `ianhanniballake` pointed out in his comment, I needed to use `viewModelScope` instead of `lifecycleScope`. This is now resolved.

---

I am trying to use `androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope` in my Android Native Jetpack Compose app. I have the following in my `build.gradle` file:

```
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
```

I have added the following import to my `MainViewModel`:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
```

I am not getting any errors on the `import`, and if I hover over it, it seems to be telling me the correct information that I am expecting about where it is coming from:

```
public val LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope
CoroutineScope tied to this LifecycleOwner's Lifecycle.
This scope will be cancelled when the Lifecycle is destroyed.
This scope is bound to Dispatchers.Main.immediate.
  androidx.lifecycle   LifecycleOwnerKt.class 
  Gradle: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1@aar (classes.jar)
```

However, when I try to reference `lifecycleScope` in my code:

```
    fun isSplashScreenOptChecked() {
        lifecycleScope.launch() {
            userPrefRepo.shouldDisplaySplashScreen().collect {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    showSplashScreen.value = it
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public val LifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope defined in androidx.lifecycle
```

I am not sure what to do next, because I copied this code from several different examples I found online, and I seem to be doing exactly what they are.

Comment: are you koin for dependency injection by any chance

Comment: I'm using Hilt - is that a potentail source of my problem?

Comment: A `ViewModel` is not a `LifecycleOwner`, so this API isn't what you should be using at all. Did you mean to use [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope)?

Comment: I'm pretty much a newbie, so I wasn't aware that's what I needed. The examples were putting all the code in the MainActivity, which isn't what I wanted. I will give the viewModelScope a try!